# Stripe custom flux ui does not display price

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm following this step-by-step tutorial: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/quickstart?platform=web
and when i display the payment form, it does not display the price being charged : [payment form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qnA5d.png). I wanted to display on top of this form the price being charged something like that.

Comment: To display the amount, you would need to build this on your own. Alternatively, you can use their prebuilt Checkout: https://docs.stripe.com/payments/checkout which shows the amount.